# TFDQuery and TFUpdate to Insert and Update a SQLite3 table

Tags: sqlite, firedac

I am using `Windows 10`, `Delphi 10.1`, `SQLite3`, `Woll2Woll DBGid` and `DataSource`.  The SQL query Is the following:

`SELECT ID, Cast(Name AS CHAR(30)) FROM Cuisine ORDER BY Name`

The `SQLite3` Data Definition is `ID: Integer` and `Name: Text`.  Deletes works fine but insert and edits work locally but they are not stored in the DB.  I expect that the problem is caused by `CAST(Name AS CHAR(30))` but I cannot figure out if this is the problem and in any event get the actual updates to the DB.  I have used `TFDQuery` alone and with a `TFDUpdateSQL component  ID` is an `AutoIncrement` Key

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround by creating a calculated string field: NameStr  I populated this field via a get text on the calculated field and then in a before post-event assigned the calculated field value to the SQL field: Name.

procedure TdmRecipe.qryCuisineBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
qryCuisineName.AsString := qryCuisineNameStr.AsString;
end;

PROCEDURE TdmRecipe.qryCuisineNameStrGetText(Sender: TField; VAR Text: STRING; DisplayText: BOOLEAN);
BEGIN
Text := qryCuisineName.AsString;
END;